# How to bind IsEnabled properties of a parent to a CheckBox of a child in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

This works if CheckBox 'test1' is defined in the same page.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=test1, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

However, if I move CheckBox 'test1' to an UserControl and then try to bind it in such a way:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=userControlElementName, Path=test1.IsChecked}" />
```

I get no results when checking the 'test1' CheckBox.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

UserControl and Button are contained in the same View.

Comment: So the button is in usercontrol1 and the checkbox is in usercontrol2, where usercontrol2 is wrapping usercontrol1?

Comment: Names have a scope. They called it.... Namescope. You moved checkbox out of where it was and into this usercontrol so it's a different namescope.  I have to guess but sounds like usecontrol and button are ultimately container in the same view i would probably bind ischecked of the checkbox to a bool property in the view's viewmodel.  I could then bind isenabled of the button. Wpf has commands which should be bound to buttons and I'd prefer to use this isenabled property with canexecute of the button's command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation, it seems to me that you are doing something wrong, since such a task arose.

But if you do not go into the essence of the general task, then for the behavior you require, you should add a property to UserControl, to which you can bind both a child and an external element.

Your UserControl:

```cs
    public partial class MyUC: UserControl
    {
        public bool ButtonIsEnabled {get; set;}
```

```xml
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonIsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUC}}}"
```

Parent Page:

```xml
<local:MyUC x:Name="userControlElementName"/>
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonIsEnabled, ElementName=userControlElementName}"/>
```

**P.S.** If you need to change the value of `ButtonIsEnabled` from Sharp, then it should be declared as a DependencyProperty.

Comment: This helped! Thanks! As for doing something wrong :D, I have a single footer in the main page for multiple Wizard View pages. And I want to bind this single footer to the data of different pages. DevExpress Wizard Control does not offer a possibility to have multiple footers